# C# Selenium FirefoxDriver ruining my code I guess?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-sheets-api

I've encountered a weird error. 
Here's the recap. 
I have a `util` class that stores all my good stuff in an app (yeah not too bright for me to store unrelated stuff in one class, code etiquette and such), it looks something like this:

```
public static class util
{
    public static IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    public static string spreadsheetId = "I won't show you my pantsu, senpai!";
    //more definitions and some methods here....
}
```

My Main method is almost a direct copy of Google's Quickstart app and looks like this:

```
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
static string ApplicationName = "I";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UserCredential credential;

    using (var stream =
        new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }

    // Create Google Sheets API service.
    var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });

    string spreadsheetId = util.spreadsheetId;
    //BELOW IS STUFF THAT DOESN'T GET EXECUTED DUE TO EXCEPTION, READ ON!
}
```

So! As  it is - works just fine technically speaking. But, due to some testing related stuff I need to switch my `util.driver` to `new FirefoxDriver()`. And guess what, when I do that the exception `System.TypeInitializationException` "Initializer of type .util returned an exception" is thrown by the `string spreadsheetId = util.spreadsheetId;` line.
How is this even possible?
Also, geckodriver, that is needed for firefoxdriver, is present in folder, but the console does scream alot about "Remote host returned an error:404 not found", no clue what's that about - does not happen with PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.TypeInitializationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is an exception that is thrown as a wrapper around the exception thrown by the class initializer. This class cannot be inherited. When a class initializer fails to initialize a type, a TypeInitializationException is created and passed a reference to the exception thrown by the type's class initializer. As referred in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353488/typeinitializationexception-when-doing-action-with-an-element-in-c-selenium), check your static parameter. Most commonly, a TypeInitializationException exception is thrown when a [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx#Static) is unable to instantiate a type.

Comment: Yeah thanks! It turns out a static member initialization I had in the util was misbehaving - moved them to the method one by one and pinpointed the bugger.